# Install pip packages on spyder

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

How can I install nrlmsise00 on Spyder via pip?

```
pip install nrlmsise00
```

Gives this error:

```
Failed building wheel for nrlmsise00... legacy-install-failure
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: @LorenzoMogicato, Failed building wheel for nrlmsise00........ legacy-install-failure